# Scalar udf abysmal performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, functions

I have a udf. It is essentially a case statement, using `if`s instead and multiple "broken" assignments of the same variable, see code below.

It does not access *any* table. Still, on one of my servers, it causes abysmall performance. I am talking tens of minutes and killing it makes it rollback for multiples of tens of minutes (!).

The code:

```
--select [dbo].[f_gmen]('Defaults')
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[f_gmen](@cssname nvarchar(50))
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
as
begin
declare @return         nvarchar(max)
declare @colorcolumn    nvarchar(max)

set @colorcolumn =  N'h'            
                
if @cssname = 'Default'
begin
    set @return = N'j'                  
    set @return = @return +N'j'             
    set @return = @return +N'j'         
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return + @colorcolumn
end

if @cssname = 'Blue'
begin
    set @return = N'j'                  
    set @return = @return +N'j'             
    set @return = @return +N'j'         
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return + @colorcolumn
end

if @cssname = 'Green'
begin
    set @return = N'j'                  
    set @return = @return +N'j'             
    set @return = @return +N'j'         
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return + @colorcolumn
end

if @cssname = 'Brown'
begin
    set @return = N'j'                  
    set @return = @return +N'j'             
    set @return = @return +N'j'         
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return + @colorcolumn
end

if @cssname = 'Grey'
begin
    set @return = N'j'                  
    set @return = @return +N'j'             
    set @return = @return +N'j'         
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return +N'j'     
    set @return = @return + @colorcolumn
end

RETURN @return 

end
GO
```

While I've stripped the true business part from it, this exact code causes as much problems as the original!
By playing around I noticed:

1. There seems to be some strange correlation between how many `if`s are uncommented. If I have only one or two uncommented, it actually runs within 2 seconds - uncomment another one and it starts taking minutes
2. Replacing the string additions with `+=` does not correct the problem
3. Keeping the same structure but using multiple variables as in-between steps makes it fast again:

   if @cssname = 'Default'
   begin
   set @return = N'j'
   set @return2 = @return +N'j'
   set @return3 = @return2 +N'j'
   set @return4 = @return3 +N'j'
   set @return5 = @return4 +N'j'
   set @return6 = @return5 + @colorcolumn
   end
4. The plan doesn't show anything interesting imo. Just a few scalar operations. Here's one of them: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H10pwzVba
5. The same code runs in 0 time in another server!
6. I tried both sp_recompile as well as DBCC FREEPROCCACHE, with no observed changes in performance

@@version:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) 
    Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 
    Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
    Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)
```

What causes this strange behaviour?

Comment: Is this the estimated execution plan? If so, providing the actual execution plan *may* provide more clues.

Comment: I am not sure; this plan was taken through dmvs' plan_handle while it was running

Comment: Yea that would be an estimated plan. Any way to run it to completion to get the full actual plan? FWIW, scalar UDFs are an antonym for performant.

Comment: I am trying to get one, at least with a few "colors" "active" so that it ends at some point. If there are many, I do not even see the query plan showing on the UI, and there are TONS of CPU on that spid as well as long rollback(?) time

Comment: Here: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1dB0US-T That one took 6 seconds, so it's kind of a sweet spot, showing some delay but not breaking the system. I used 2 "colors" in it.

Comment: Thanks, you should add that link to your post so others see it. Is the code of the function you provided the actual code or is it obfuscated?...I'm unsure what it's trying to do by looking at it and it seems every `IF` case is redundantly doing the same exact thing. I think this scalar function is rewritable in an efficient way as a single statement table-valued function, but I'm hesitant to write something up for you if this isn't the actual code.

Comment: @J.D. I already replaced the code with a single case statement and it works fine. I still want to find the cause as knowledge. The code is the actual function - it's been shortened by me to present a more "minimal" case here. The string literals are initially different, they just return parts of a css text. The multiple assignments are not really needed, and once they disappear it runs fast again - but there is no visible reason for such behaviour, right?

Comment: What is the query that uses the UDF (and its actual execution plan)? If it's called just once for a single scalar value then the issue doesn't make sense. But if it's being called against a set of rows, then it's possible it's just normal UDF crappiness.

Comment: It really is called once!! `select [dbo].[f_gmen]('Defaults')` This has been the test case the entire time.

Comment: That's weird then. Can you please provide the `@@version` of the other server that the function works on?

Comment: @J.D. Off for the weekend, but will do so when coming back, maybe even try a few more  server versions, and update the original with all the added info.

Comment: Welp I think your problematic instance is likely a bug in the RTM version of 2019. I've seen multiple function specific bugs in 2019 RTM that went away on upgrade. So I'd suggest try updating to the latest version. I bet your working instance is a newer version.

Comment: @J.D. Interesting. My working instance is almost certainly 2017.

Comment: Well if it's a completely different major version number then yea that also makes sense. 2019 RTM had a lot of bugs, and I personally experienced function specific ones. I wouldn't doubt updating solves your problem. In general, one shouldn't use the RTM version ever, when there's newer updates.